# How do I overcome my fear of quadratic equations, cubic polynomials etc?

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, quadratics, cubics

I love math but whenever it comes to quadratic equations or polynomials I am unable to understand and solve questions from such topic... I feel very sad... What should I do overcome this fear? How can I make my concept strong in this topic?

Comment: It's better to ask specific questions about polynomials - learning the things you don't understand bit by bit is definitely better than trying to tackle your fear of the subject in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the easiest questions you find. Do those until you feel you can do them inside out and then progress to slightly more challenging ones. Keep doing this. Math is hard. You just need to take it one step at a time and your confidence will come gradually.